# Report to get all roles in salesforce (with assigned users and without users)

Tags: soql, reporting

I need a report that shows all roles. Currently I have created a report on user which shows those roles which have users assigned, but I need to show all roles with or without users assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the below Solutions.But still if i need to show report with roles (assigned to active users and without users) then what is the solution to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run a report against the UserRole object but you can try this instead:

1. Go into the Developer Console and select the SOQL query tab or you can login to workbench.developerforce.com.
2. Go to the Queries Menu/SOQL Query
3. Paste this query in the query box and click the Execute (or Query) button.

This query selects all roles that are not found in the User table.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM UserRole
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE UserRoleId !='000000000000000')
```

This is what you get:

[image]

You can then run the same query a bit modified to get all Roles that are assigned

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM UserRole
WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE UserRoleId !='000000000000000')
```

The results can be placed in excel and then imported to a custom object where you can create a report on it if you wanted.

Comment: Appriciate the early Response.

Comment: Thanks very much.Here (id=0000000000000000)?.does it mean blank value

Comment: Yes.

If you liked the answer, why not express it by voting for it. I hope that it helped.

Comment: yes.Sure here is the vote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a report, but you could use something like the following in an execute anonymous window, which would give you an output with the names of the roles not being used.
You may want to add in criteria to only look at active users, or maybe remove community/partner users.

```
Map<Id, UserRole> roles = new Map<Id, UserRole>([SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM UserRole]);

List<User> users = [SELECT Id, UserRoleId FROM User];

List<String> rolesWithoutUsers = new List<String>();

for(User theUser : users)
{
    roles.remove(theUser.UserRoleId);
}

for(UserRole theRole : roles.values())
{
    rolesWithoutUsers.add(theRole.Name);
}

system.debug(rolesWithoutUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the rest api the endpoint you can use **user24509** response with `/services/data/v37.0/queryAll?q=SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE UserRoleId !='000000000000000')`